# Problems with SQLite in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I'm having problems with SQLite in Android. Eclipse does not report any error in sintax, but when the OnClickListener is called in this  app, I have this:

> the application has stopped unexpectedly

This is the OnClickListener code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText usernameTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
            String username = usernameTxt.getText().toString();
            SQL users = new SQL(getApplicationContext(), "loopr", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase db = users.getWritableDatabase();

            if (db != null){
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES ('"+username+"')");
            }
        }
```

And this is the SQL.java code:

```
public class SQL extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE users (name TEXT)";
    public SQL(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(sqlCreate);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int before, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users");
    }

}
```

Where is the problem? I'm a beginner in Android and I need help. Thanks :)

**EDIT 1:**
LogCat:

```
02-17 20:33:16.717: D/ddm-heap(22023): Got feature list request
02-17 20:34:53.307: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22023): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
02-17 20:35:52.857: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22215): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
02-17 20:53:01.747: D/AndroidRuntime(22695): Shutting down VM
02-17 20:53:01.747: W/dalvikvm(22695): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e160)
02-17 20:53:01.747: E/AndroidRuntime(22695): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at com.loopr.LooprActivity$1.onClick(LooprActivity.java:43)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2397)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4212)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6616)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3742)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:981)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:981)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:981)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2064)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-17 20:53:01.767: E/AndroidRuntime(22695):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 20:53:01.777: E/SemcCheckin(22695): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
02-17 20:53:01.787: I/dalvikvm(22695): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
02-17 20:53:01.797: I/dalvikvm(22695): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-17 20:53:03.437: I/Process(22695): Sending signal. PID: 22695 SIG: 9
02-17 20:56:08.947: D/AndroidRuntime(22861): Shutting down VM
02-17 20:56:08.957: W/dalvikvm(22861): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e160)
02-17 20:56:08.957: E/AndroidRuntime(22861): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at com.loopr.LooprActivity$1.onClick(LooprActivity.java:43)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2397)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4212)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6616)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3742)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:981)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:981)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:981)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2064)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-17 20:56:08.977: E/AndroidRuntime(22861):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 20:56:08.997: E/SemcCheckin(22861): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
02-17 20:56:09.117: I/dalvikvm(22861): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
02-17 20:56:09.127: I/dalvikvm(22861): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-17 20:56:31.077: D/AndroidRuntime(23027): Shutting down VM
02-17 20:56:31.077: W/dalvikvm(23027): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e160)
02-17 20:56:31.077: E/AndroidRuntime(23027): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at com.loopr.LooprActivity$1.onClick(LooprActivity.java:43)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2397)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4212)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6616)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3742)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:981)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:981)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:981)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2064)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-17 20:56:31.087: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 20:56:31.097: E/SemcCheckin(23027): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
```

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the LogCat view in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your runtime error. Also, do not use `getApplicationContext()` here -- `this` will work just fine.

Comment: Post the stacktrace with the `Exception` from the `Logcat`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I edited the post with the LogCat log that appears in Eclipse :) Sorry for the bad formatting of the log.

Comment: Reformatted logCat as code to maintain proper line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is classcast exception (java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView 02-17 20:53:01.767:).  It seems nameTxt is TextView and you are trying to convert to EditText.

```
EditText usernameTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
```

Use valid EditText inside `findViewById(....)`;

Comment: Or, possibly, your resource IDs are a bit out of sync with the rest of your code. In Eclipse, try Project > Clean from the main menu.

Comment: Thank you @thinksteep, that was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Go to menu project> Clean then select the "clean project selected below" 
Check it the corresponding project,then select ok button.